# Significato di "arrivare in legno"

Tags: meaning

Leggendo un articolo su Garibaldi, ho trovato questo:

> Lo stato de inoltrata gravidanza della marchesina era di ricondursi alla sua relazione clandestina con Caroli che si voleva **arrivasse in legno** a notte fitta sotto le mura del giardino di Fino e che scavalcatolo raggiunse l'amante.

Non riesco a trovare il significato di "arrivare in legno".

Mille grazie!

Comment: Credo che il significato di "legno" nel brano sia quello di "carro, carrozza", come si può vedere al numero **6** della [voce "legno" sul *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI08/00000939.jpg). Mi sembra sia l'unica accezione che possa avere senso in questo contesto.

Comment: Sinedocche o metonimia?

Answer (score 6):

Ho letto tutte le accezioni che appaiono alla [voce "legno" sul *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI08/00000939.jpg) e l'unica che ha senso nel contesto del brano citato è la numero 6:

> Carro, carrozza.

Quindi "arrivare in legno" significa in questo contesto "arrivare in carrozza".

Un autore che usa spesso il termine "legno" con questo senso è Federigo Tozzi. Eccone un esempio tratto dal romanzo [*Con gli occhi chiusi*](https://www.liberliber.it/online/autori/autori-t/federigo-tozzi/con-gli-occhi-chiusi/), del primo Novecento (grassetto mio):

> Finalmente, Domenico con un colpo del suo tovagliolo si levò le briciole da sopra i calzoni; si fece spolverare da Rebecca e untare le scarpe da Tiburzi, dando nel frattempo qualche ordine. In punta di piedi andò dietro il figlio che tamburellava con le dita sopra un vetro, accompagnando il mugolìo della sua voce a bocca chiusa; gli dette una manata sul collo, e disse: – Vieni in campagna con me. Pietro, senza rispondere niente, saltò sul **legno** già attaccato; e furono a Poggio a' Meli poco prima del tramonto.

---

**Nota:** Nei commenti si è menzionato che, nel caso che le mura del giardino dessero su un canale, potrebbe avere anche senso un'altra delle accezioni di "legno", quella che corrisponde al numero **5** della [stessa voce del *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI08/00000938.jpg):

> Imbarcazione, bastimento, nave, barca.

Tuttavia, su questo [libro](https://books.google.es/books?id=QBMNAQAAIAAJ&q=%22arrivasse+in+legno+a+notte+fitta+sotto%22&dq=%22arrivasse+in+legno+a+notte+fitta+sotto%22&hl=ca&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwili7Wd58zrAhUIx4UKHZ4JA_YQ6AEwAHoECAAQAQ) ho potuto vedere che il passo citato nella domanda si basa su un documento storico, in cui appare l'espressione "sotto le mura del giardino di Fino". Il testo fa riferimento a [Giuseppina Raimondi](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giuseppina_Raimondi). [*Fino*](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fino_Mornasco) sarebbe il luogo di nascita della Raimondi, in cui abitava quando ebbe la relazione clandestina con Caroli menzionata nel brano. Non ho trovato nessuna fonte che parli dell'esistenza di canali a Fino, per cui l'ipotesi che "legno" faccia riferimento a una barca mi sembra poco plausibile.

Comment: Grazie Charo. Veramente ha senso così.  Ti ringrazio per il legame al dizionario online.

Comment: @Humberto:     Ho usato questo dizionario perché è il più completo: così siamo sicuri di non aver dimenticato nessuna possibile accezione.

Comment: ho sentito usare "legno" anche per indicare una barca.

Comment: Sì, lo so, @RiccardoDeContardi, lo usa molto Dante, per esempio. E appare anche sul GDLI (http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI08/00000938.jpg). Però mi sembra un po' strano arrivare sotto le mura di un giardino in barca.

Comment: @Charo Magari il muro del giardino dà su un canale.

Comment: Secondo te questa altra possibilità di dovrebbe aggiungere alla risposta, @egreg?

Comment: @Charo Non conosco il libro.

Comment: @egreg: Il testo sembra riferirsi a un documento storico, di cui ho potuto leggere un pezzettino [qui](https://books.google.es/books?id=QBMNAQAAIAAJ&q=%22arrivasse+in+legno+a+notte+fitta+sotto%22&dq=%22arrivasse+in+legno+a+notte+fitta+sotto%22&hl=ca&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwili7Wd58zrAhUIx4UKHZ4JA_YQ6AEwAHoECAAQAQ): ho visto che dice "sotto le mura del giardino di Fino". Fino sarebbe il luogo di nascita di [Giuseppina Raimondi](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giuseppina_Raimondi). Non so se si tratti di un posto con canali.

Comment: La [Wikipedia](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fino_Mornasco) non menziona che ci siano canali a Fino, per cui escluderei la possibilità che si tratti di una barca.

Comment: Certo, si tratta di una racconto storico delle done di Garibaldi.  Il pezzo venne dalla storia della marchesina Raimondi, abitava nella villa Raimondi a Fino Mornasco.

Comment: Va bene, @RiccardoDeContardi: ho menzionato nella risposta che "legno" può anche voler dire "barca", spiegando le ragioni per cui mi sembra poco plausibile che questo sia il senso del termine nel contesto del brano citato.